# color environment text is not converted in htlatex

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

I have using `pdflatex` to get the `color` environment text. But when using `htlatex` the color and the `environment content (Note)` is not converting. Please find the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{midblue}{cmyk}{1,0,0.16,0.09}
\newcommand{\notefont}{\small\sffamily\color{midblue}}
\newenvironment{notelist}{%
\begin{itemize}
   \item[\label={\notefont Note:}]
}{%
 \end{itemize}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\begin{notelist}
\item A template for fractions may be obtained by pressing.
\end{notelist}
\begin{notelist}
\item For all calculations you can also use the \textbf{Scratchpad}.
\item For details of the use of the Scratchpad and general use of the calculator with
operating system 3.0 refer to the Appendix Computer Algebra System (TI-Nspire).
\end{notelist}
\end{document}
```

How to get the `color environment` and `colored framebox` environement in `htlatex`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Colors are supported by `tex4ht` but there are two points:

`\color` command isn't supported:

> The \Verb!\color{red}! instruction might be problematic since it does
>   not on its own determine the extent of the text to be colored.  As a
>   result, its effect can cross logical boundaries. That is against the
>   philosophy of markup languages in general and of XML in particular.
>
> It is possible to implement the \Verb!\color{...}! feature but I'm not
>   sure it is desirable to do so.  I think it is preferable to expect
>   users to use commands of the form \Verb!\textcolor{red}{...}! for code
>   fragments.

so it is better to use `\textcolor`

each color has to be declared for `tex4ht` with command in the form:

```
 \Configure{HColor}{colorname}{csscode}
```

Now back to your code. I think that:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item[\label={\notefont Note:}]
}{%
```

is wrong, you are calling `\label` command with `=` as argument. It should be:

```
\begin{itemize}
   \item[{\notefont Note:}]
}{%
```

but this doesn't work with `tex4ht` for some reason. But there is also no reason to use `\item` this way, you may just define `notelist` environment this way:

```
\definecolor{notecolor}{cmyk}{1,0,0.16,0.09}
\newenvironment{notelist}{%
  \leavevmode\noindent{\notefont\textcolor{notecolor}{Note:}}
  \begin{itemize}
}{%
 \end{itemize}%
}
```

We defined `notecolor` to be used here, because I think it is better to use logical names, it will enable you to change the color easily in the future. Now you need to create a custom config file and put these declarations:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\newcommand\colortohtml[2]{%
\extractcolorspec{#1}{\tmp}%
\expandafter\convertcolorspec\tmp{HTML}#2
}
\newcommand\declarehcolor[1]{%
\colortohtml{#1}\tmp%
\Configure{HColor}{#1}{\#\tmp}%
}
\declarehcolor{notecolor}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

commands from `xcolor` package are used here to convert named color to rgb value. note that when you use `cmyk` colors, the resulting color may be slightly different due to the conversion.

Now compile the file with

```
htlatex filename cfgname
```

[image]

Comment: How do achieve `framebox` from `For all calculations....` to end of `(TI-Nspire).` (Including `itemize`).

Comment: @Balaji could you post some example of what you have in mind?

Comment: I will post in new question.

Comment: I do not think one can use `\textcolor` everywhere.  How would you use it in a column specification?  Like in `>{\color{red}}c` to color and center a given column in a tabular environment?

Comment: @user29363 of course not everywhere, for tables or color boxes you need to use different means. `\textcolor` should be used only for marking colorized chunk of text

Comment: Mh, pretty sure I used exactly the configuration above. However, executing ```xhlatex filename "myhtml,xhtml,charset=utf-8,fn-in" "-cunihtf -utf8``` results into an error: ```! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document} in `myhtml.cfg'.``` - ideas?

Comment: @Alex did you copy really the whole .cfg file? It needs to contain `\begin{document}` line

Comment: Can you give a working example of a config file with a working syntax for \Configure{HColor}{colorname}{csscode}, I can't get it to translate \textcolor{red}{blah} properly.

Comment: @EmanueleViola sure, but it would be better if you could post a new question, so it can be easier searchable in the future

Comment: @michal.h21I just put the question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390127/textcolor-with-tex4ht