# \textcolor with tex4ht

Tags: color, tex4ht

This is a question about getting colors with tex4ht.  The issue was discussed e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195471/color-environment-text-is-not-converted-in-htlatex/195677?noredirect=1#comment968069_195677), where a suggestion was made, which however I can't get to work.  I asked a comment there and it was suggested to make a new question, so here it goes:

Can you give a working example of a config file with a working syntax for `\Configure{HColor}{colorname}{csscode}`, I can't get it to translate `\textcolor{red}{blah}` properly.

More precisely, if I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[unicode=true]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{\textcolor{red}{WARNING}}

\end{document}
```

and I compile with tex4ht I get

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" ?>  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">   <!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   >  <head>    <title></title>  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />  <meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />  <meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/)" />  <!-- html,xhtml,-css,NoFonts -->  <meta name="src" content="post2.tex" />  <meta name="date" content="2017-09-07 08:56:00" />  </head>
<body  > <p style="text-align:justify"><span class="paragraphHead"><a   id="x1-1000"></a><span id="textcolor1">WARNING</span></span>    </p>    </body></html>
```

which does not look red on a browser. Note the command

```
<span id="textcolor1">WARNING</span></span>
```

My htlatex options are xhtml,-css,NoFonts

Comment: You disable generation of the `css` file with the `-css` option.

Comment: How can I have colors with the -css option?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the CSS file? It wouldn't be possible in an straight-forward way.

Comment: Because free wordpress does not support it.  Is it really so hard to tell tex4ht how to interpret the textcolor command?

Comment: I found a way hot to do it, see the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `xcolor` package, you shouldn't need to configure anything, colors should work out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{rgb}{1,0.2,0.2}
\begin{document}

Helo world \textcolor{red}{blah}. And I can use \textcolor{mycolor}{my color}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really want to redefine it in the `.cfg` file, you need to use valid CSS color declaration, like `#0012FF`. You must escape the `#` character:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{HColor}{mycolor}{\#0012FF}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

[image]

Edit:

`tex4ht` saves the colors in the CSS file. Because you don't want to use the CSS file, we must use a trick to save the colors directly in the `style` attribute of element around the colored text. Try this `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\makeatletter
\Configure{textcolor}{\HCode{<span style="color:\#\tsf@color;">}}{\HCode{</span>}}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble

% redefine \textcolor command
\let\oldtextcolor\textcolor

\renewcommand\textcolor[2]{%
  % we need to convert the current color to hexadecimal form usable in the style attribute
  % the \tsf@color macro is used in the \Configure{textcolor} configuration to insert the
  % CSS color
  \extractcolorspec{#1}{\tsf@color}%
  \expandafter\convertcolorspec\tsf@color{HTML}\tsf@color%
  % call the original command
  \oldtextcolor{#1}{#2}%
}%
\makeatother
```

It produces the following HTML:

```xml
<p class="noindent" >Helo world <span style="color:FF0000;">blah</span>. And I can use <span style="color:FF3333;">my color</span>. </p>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work for me.  I added a MWE that shows my output.  I tried both with xcolor and without.  Maybe there's something in my options that's wrong?

Comment: Beatiful, thanks, it works! For some reason it doesn't work if I apply it to section headers, but I haven't debugged.